# Why do I get a 'Connection closed' error when trying to branch a Launchpad branch?

Tags: ssh, launchpad, bazaar

When I try to branch any Launchpad branch I keep getting the following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

and the branching fails.

Occasionally it works as normal but most of the time I get this error.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're seeing, and it seems like it's not a client-side issue, is probably a problem with the Launchpad servers.

However, I can't reproduce this at the moment. For production issues with Launchpad it's usually best to ask in the #launchpad channel on IRC or in the "Answers" section on Launchpad itself.

Comment: I don't have this issue any more so I'm guessing it was just a temporary problem on their end.

Comment: I have this problem . All the time any idea why this happens ?